# Webform localization string translation

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n

I am using the webform localization module for string translation of my webform components. I have created a custom module that outputs the data but can not get the translation to work. I am using the t() function as follows passing in the string, the language and the context of component 1 title on node id 50

```
t('New radios', array(), array('langcode' => 'fr', 'context' => '50:1:#title'))
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong would be great.

Comment: What would Webform Localization have to do with strings created in code? I believed it's for strings one wrote in webform UI, am I missing something?

Comment: Webform localization module exposed strings for string translation which all works ok. In my module i am grabbing submission data and would like to return the translated questions, options and labels. In the code above I am trying to return the french translation of the string "New radios"

Comment: I got it working with the following i18n_string_translate('webform:50:1:#title', 'New Radios', array('langcode' => 'fr'))